# How to check the points initial and final point of the line which is clicked in a svg polyline or polygon?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, svg

I am making a map editor for my game. I have an svg which will contain many `<polyline>`. Whenever user clicks on any line of the `<polyline>`. I two things as information. The coordinates where the mouse was clicked and all the points of that polyline in order.

I want to check what are those two points between which the line was clicked.

For that I have used distance formula. If `AB` is a line and we want to check whether the point `C` lies on that line or not. We will check if distance of `AB` is equal to `BC + AC`.

Below is my code.

```js
const poly = document.getElementById("poly");

poly.onclick = function(e){
  const mousePos = [e.clientX,e.clientY];
  //console.log(mousePos)
  const points = poly.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(x => x.split(',').map(Number));
  const res= points.find((p, i) => {
    let prevPoint = points[i-1];
    if(i === 0){
      prevPoint = points[points.length - 1];
    }
    return arePointsCollinear(prevPoint, p, mousePos)
  });
  if(res){
    console.log(res);
  }
}

const getDistance = (pointA, pointB) => {
   const dx = Math.pow(pointA[0] - pointB[0], 2);
   const dy = Math.pow(pointA[1] - pointB[1], 2);
   return Math.sqrt(dx + dy);
};

const arePointsCollinear = (
   pointA,
   pointB,
   pointC
) => {
   const totalDistance = getDistance(pointA, pointB);
   const deltaAC = getDistance(pointA, pointC);
   const deltaBC = getDistance(pointB, pointC);
   return totalDistance === deltaAC + deltaBC;
};
```

```css
svg polyline{
  fill:none;
  stroke:black;
  stroke-width: 10
}
svg{
height:500px;
width:500px;
}
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polyline id="poly" points="100,100 150,200 250,150 100,100"/>
</svg>
```

The problem in above code is that it doesn't consider the width of the line. Means that we have precisely click at very center of line to get answer. I want that whenever I click on line it should tell the two points of that line.

Comment: How is my answer Maheer Ali?

Comment: @AlexL Its working fine now. The previous one with dots on the corners was not working but this one is cool. Ty

Comment: Perfect! Good to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something working,

https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/rNaERKa

[image]

HTML:

```
<svg id="svg" height="500" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
    <polyline id="poly" points="100,100 150,200 250,150 100,100"/>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
const svg = document.getElementById("svg");
const poly = document.getElementById("poly");
const poly_width = getComputedStyle(poly)['stroke-width'];
console.log(parseInt(poly_width));
const half_width = parseInt(poly_width) / 2;

poly.onclick = function(e){
  const mousePos = [e.clientX,e.clientY];
  console.log(mousePos)
  const points = poly.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(x => x.split(',').map(Number));
  const res= points.find((p, i) => {
    let prevPoint = points[i-1];
    if(i === 0){
      prevPoint = points[points.length - 1];
    }
    return arePointsCollinear(prevPoint, p, mousePos)
  });
  if(res){
    console.log(res);
    const NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    const circle = document.createElementNS(NS,'circle');
    circle.setAttribute('r', '5');
    circle.setAttribute('cx', res[0]);
    circle.setAttribute('cy', res[1]);
    svg.appendChild(circle);
    console.log('circle');
  }
}

const getDistance = (pointA, pointB) => {
   const dx = Math.pow(pointA[0] - pointB[0], 2);
   const dy = Math.pow(pointA[1] - pointB[1], 2);
   return Math.sqrt(dx + dy);
};

const arePointsCollinear = (
   pointA,
   pointB,
   pointC
) => {
   const totalDistance = getDistance(pointA, pointB);
   const deltaAC = getDistance(pointA, pointC);
   const deltaBC = getDistance(pointB, pointC);
   return deltaAC + deltaBC <= Math.sqrt(totalDistance**2 + half_width**2);
};
```

Most important line is `return deltaAC + deltaBC <= Math.sqrt(totalDistance**2 + half_width**2);` - and I drew a diagram to explain where this comes from:

[image]

Basically, you need to account for the longest path that is still inside the stroke-width. I believe that is the square root of ( lengthAB^2 plus half_stroke-width^2 )

**UPDATE**

If you want to add lines instead you need to change `points.find()` to `points.findIndex()` then you can use the index and the prevIndex to draw a line between the points:

[image]

JS:

```
const svg = document.getElementById("svg");
const poly = document.getElementById("poly");
const poly_width = getComputedStyle(poly)['stroke-width'];
console.log(parseInt(poly_width));
const half_width = parseInt(poly_width) / 2;

poly.onclick = function(e){
  const mousePos = [e.clientX,e.clientY];
  console.log(mousePos)
  const points = poly.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(x => x.split(',').map(Number));
  const res= points.findIndex((p, i) => {
    let prevPoint = points[i-1];
    if(i === 0){
      prevPoint = points[points.length - 1];
    }
    return arePointsCollinear(prevPoint, p, mousePos)
  });
  if(res != -1){
    console.log(res);
    const NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
    const line = document.createElementNS(NS,'line')
    // const circle = document.createElementNS(NS,'circle');
    // circle.setAttribute('r', '5');
    // circle.setAttribute('cx', points[res][0]);
    // circle.setAttribute('cy', points[res][1]);
    // svg.appendChild(circle);
    // console.log('circle');

    line.setAttribute('x1', points[res][0]);
    line.setAttribute('y1', points[res][1]);
    let prevIndex = (res === 0) ? (points.length - 1) : res - 1;
    line.setAttribute('x2', points[prevIndex][0]);
    line.setAttribute('y2', points[prevIndex][1]);
    svg.appendChild(line);
    console.log('line');
  }
}

const getDistance = (pointA, pointB) => {
   const dx = Math.pow(pointA[0] - pointB[0], 2);
   const dy = Math.pow(pointA[1] - pointB[1], 2);
   return Math.sqrt(dx + dy);
};

const arePointsCollinear = (
   pointA,
   pointB,
   pointC
) => {
   const totalDistance = getDistance(pointA, pointB);
   const deltaAC = getDistance(pointA, pointC);
   const deltaBC = getDistance(pointB, pointC);
   return deltaAC + deltaBC <= Math.sqrt(totalDistance**2 + (2*half_width)**2);
};
```